# C# - Write back data to table with IDENTITY

Tags: c#, treeview

We're using a C# Desktop application to pull data from an Azure SQL DB. We have a table containing a listview of unstructured data that the customer can structure in a treeview, setting up hierarchies, etc.

They can have multiple of these structures, and the application allows them to create and/or edit these. This involves creating some custom entities that are not ListIDs that will act as parent of the ListIDs, or as parent of other parents.

Very simplified, our database schema contains 1 table with all the data of the unstructured list:

```
CREATE TABLE myList (
  ListID int IDENTITY
  , ListDescription nvarchar(50)
)
```

1 table to contain the structures:

```
CREATE TABLE myStructure (
  StructureID int IDENTITY
  , StructureDescription nvarchar(50)
)
```

And finally 1 table to contain the structured list:

```
CREATE TABLE myStructuredList (
  StructuredListID int IDENTITY -- InternalID
  , StructureID int -- ID of the selected structure
  , Level smallint -- Level in the hierarchy (0 = root, 1 = Just below root, etc.)
  , LevelName nvarchar(50) -- Name of the level
  , ParentID int -- Which StructureListID is the parent?
  , ListID int -- ID of the selectedList
)
```

The C# project uses classes to represent the data and these are populated from the database and added to Lists.

My original thought was to have the Treeview component handle creating new StructuredListIDs for the parent levels created. Whenever the Treeview gets saved, it would simply wipe the existing entries with the selected StructureID, and add the new structure.

However, after putting some thought into things, this seems impractical for multiple reasons, 1 being that recently it was suggested to save any change to the treeview immediately to the database, meaning there would be a *lot* of deletions/inserts. Another being that if multiple users would be working at the same time, there is a chance that the IDENTITY column values could get out of sync. Or, that when things are being moved around within the treeview, parentIds might be shifted.

I'm currently leaning to adding a new column to the model that would sort of be similar to the StructuredListID, but internally (rather than as an IDENTITY) for the TreeView, to properly establish the parent/child representation, because obviously when deleting and inserting data, the IDENTITY column values would be shifting.

Would this be the recommended approach, or am I overlooking something very obvious?